# In OFDM, does the parameter time offset is important if there is only one mobile in the cell?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, synchronization, lte

I am learning about OFDM, and in my reading, I have noticed that (mentioned everywhere) synchronization is a very critical aspect of OFDM. Here, I am writing in the context of time synchronization (time offset).

What I understood that time offset is important if there are multiple transmitting mobiles in a cell, and due to different delays in each path it is difficult to find the frame starting time at the receiver. Will this concept apply if there is only a single mobile transmitting in a cell?

Comment: Yes, it is. Your receiver will need to be well synchronized in time, or else its dft will be meaningless